# Making the login/logout function using AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, asyncstorage

I am making my first React Native app and I am in the process of making the login/logout functions of the app. I am trying to make the app remember the logged in user by using AsyncStorage. here's my code:

app.js-

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Login from './components/login'
import Signup from './components/signup'
import Home from './components/home'
import Profile from './components/profile';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback, Component} from 'react'




const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Signup: {screen: Signup},
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Profile: {screen: Profile},
  
});

const AppNavigator2 = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Signup: {screen: Signup},
  Profile: {screen: Profile},
  
});

const getData = async () => {
  try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@userauthkey')
      if (value !== null) {
          return value
      } else {
          return false
      }
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
  }
}



const ch = async () => {
  const c = await getData();
  if (c) {
    
    console.log(c)
    return true 
  } else {
    return false
  }
};

const check = ch()
console.log(check)

const App = createAppContainer(  check ? AppNavigator2 : AppNavigator )




export default App;
```

When I run this the app automaticly goes to "AppNavigator2" regardless of whether the user is logged in or not. I checked the console and "check" does not show anything. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the variable `check` is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

In order to have the boolean value you're expecting, you should wait for the async function `ch` to return the correct value.

You can achieve that by adding the keyword `await` when invoking the function `ch`.

`const check = await ch();`

Comment: When I add await I get unexpected token error

Comment: The await operator works in async functions that's why you have this error. You can, for instance, render the right AppNavigator dynamically using a component and performing the check in an async function.